# When clicking div append selected to drop down menu

Tags: javascript, list, select, onclick

Gday,

I know this might sound crazy but what would be the easiest way to append the word **selected** to a drop down menu when a div is clicked.

You see i have divs with images in them acting as template views. If a template image / div is clicked i need to append selected to the dropdown menu where the option to select the template layout is. I would rather give people the option to click a template rather than just choosing it from a drop doiwn. But both will .

```
Do i do an onclick append?
```

Which would be the right command in javascript / jquery to insert the word selected into a

```
<option value="<?php echo $getlayouts;?>" ><?php echo $FileName;?></option>
```

Cheers.
Jonnypixel

Answer (score 0):

To select an `option` you don't change its `selected` property, you change the `selectedIndex` property of the `select`.

Example:

```
window.onload = function(){
  document.getElementById('IdOfTheDiv').onclick = function(){
    document.getElementById('IdOfTheSelect').selectedIndex = 2;
  };
};
```

Comment: thanks Guffa trying now. Makes sense :). Why Guffa? that your name?

Comment: Hi again Guffa, it works but how does the selectedIndex = 2 work. At the moment the snippet you provided sits outside the loop. I probably should have said i have a loop. One loops through and displays my template layouts and then below that another loops through the same but displays the select menu .

Comment: @jonnypixel: The index that you set is the zero based index of the `option` in the `select`. Setting `selectedIndex` to `2` will make the third option selected. If you have a loop, you would typically use the loop counter as the index of the option.

Comment: aha! so i place the script inside the loop and create  a unique div. Or can i somehow get the unique template name inside the function(template,indexid) and then apply like that? I'll try it but am not tottaly sure it will work.

Comment: It doesn't matter how you bind the event or how you get a reference to the div. If you write the event handler code directly in the element (i.e. `onclick="..."`) then you don't need a unique id on the div.

Comment: aha yes i was just trying that. But im still confused as to how i get the index number i need. As the only values i have in my loop are the template name. Do i have to do some sort of i++ or something of that sort?

Comment: @jonnypixel: You could loop through the options and look for the value: `sel=document.getElementById('IdOfTheSelect');for(var i=0;i<sel.options.length;i++)if(sel.options[i].value==templatename){sel.selectedIndex=i;break;}`.

Answer (score 0):

You can insert selected attribute to an option tag based on its value

```
$('select').children('option[value=somevalue]').attr('selected',true);
```

Comment: Hi Faraz, i have tried yours like this: onclick="$('select#selectMenuDiv').children('option[value=<?php echo $FileName;?>]').attr('selected',true);" But it it says its null in firebug ff

Comment: I assume that you have a <select id='selectMenuDiv'> and option tag(s) with the value that you have in $FileName variable(s).
What this code does, is this simply sets the attribute selected to whatever option tag you selected.